# Magento just displays PHP code content of a class and stops

Tags: magento-ce

I have a strange issue where any page load attempts simply outputs a string of PHP code. When inspecting the source code, it reveals that it's actually the entire content of a class file as shown below. This happens on a particular server and for any page request.

The same code base and database works fine on my local environment. Any idea what might be doing this?

[image: Page doesn't load]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, the first thing that pops out is you're using a PHP short tag to start your PHP file

```
`<?`
```

You'll want to change that to

```
`<?php`
```

My guess if your server is setup with the `short_open_tag` ini set to false, which means `<?` will be interpreted as a regular bit of text.

Comment: Hmmmm yes! I completely missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Something about this old question just jumped out to me - in your screenshot you have created a **Block** which extends the **Mage_Core_Block_Template** class.

However, your block methods are named as *actions*, indicating that this may be controller code. Further, you're using `loadLayout` and `renderLayout` - both are methods that come from the `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` - again, controller code.

I believe that besides PHP short tags you likely have other issues here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, good catch! This is actually comical. I believe I was troubleshooting somebody's bug and that's just a screenshot of the source. I have no idea what this did or does.

Comment: Ha, I recognize that code from a review: https://twitter.com/fschmengler/status/608000603814526976 (luckily, the block does nothing)